# Multithreaded Producer/Consumer in C++

Tags: multithreading, c++11, producer-consumer

I am looking at multithreading and written a basic producer/consumer. I have two issues with the producer/consumer written below. 1) Even by setting the consumer sleep time lower than the producer sleep time, the producer still seems to execute quicker. 2) In the consumer I have duplicated the code in the case where the producer finishes adding to the queue, but there is still elements in the queue. Any advise for a better way of structuring the code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>

class App {
private:
    std::queue<int> m_data;
    bool m_bFinished;
    std::mutex m_Mutex;
    int m_ConsumerSleep;
    int m_ProducerSleep;
    int m_QueueSize;
public:
    App(int &MaxQueue) :m_bFinished(false), m_ConsumerSleep(1), m_ProducerSleep(5), m_QueueSize(MaxQueue){}
    void Producer() {

        for (int i = 0; i < m_QueueSize; ++i) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_Mutex);
            m_data.push(i); 
            std::cout << "Producer Thread, queue size: " << m_data.size() << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(m_ProducerSleep));
        }
        m_bFinished = true;
    }

    void Consumer() {
        while (!m_bFinished) {
            if (m_data.size() > 0) {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_Mutex);
                std::cout << "Consumer Thread, queue element: " << m_data.front() << " size: " << m_data.size() << std::endl;
                m_data.pop();
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "No elements, skipping" << std::endl;
            }
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(m_ConsumerSleep));
        }
        while (m_data.size() > 0) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_Mutex);
            std::cout << "Emptying remaining elements " << m_data.front() << std::endl;
            m_data.pop();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(m_ConsumerSleep));
        }
    }

};


int main()
{
    int QueueElements = 10;
    App app(QueueElements);
    std::thread consumer_thread(&App::Consumer, &app);
    std::thread producer_thread(&App::Producer, &app);

    producer_thread.join();
    consumer_thread.join();


    std::cout << "loop exited" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should use a condition variable instead of a delay on the consumer. This way, the consumer thread only wakes up when the queue is not empty and the producer notifies it.

That said, the reason why your producer calls are more frequent is the delay on the producer thread. It's executed while holding the mutex, so the consumer will never execute until the delay is over. You should release the mutex before calling `sleep_for`:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < m_QueueSize; ++i) {
            /* Introduce a scope to release the mutex before sleeping*/
            {
               std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_Mutex);
                m_data.push(i); 
                std::cout << "Producer Thread, queue size: " << m_data.size() << std::endl;
            } // Mutex is released here
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(m_ProducerSleep));
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use [condition_variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable). Don't use sleep for threads.

Main scheme: 
Producer pushes value under lock and signals condition_variable.

Consumer waits under lock on condition variable and checks predicate to prevent spurious wakeups.

My version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <atomic>

class App {
private:
    std::queue<int> m_data;
    std::atomic_bool m_bFinished;
    std::mutex m_Mutex;
    std::condition_variable m_cv;
    int m_QueueSize;
public:
    App(int MaxQueue) 
        : m_bFinished(false)
        , m_QueueSize(MaxQueue) 
    {}

    void Producer()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m_QueueSize; ++i) 
        {
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_Mutex);
                m_data.push(i); 
            }
            m_cv.notify_one();
            std::cout << "Producer Thread, queue size: " << m_data.size() << std::endl;
        }
        m_bFinished = true;
    }

    void Consumer() 
    {
        do
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_Mutex);
            while (m_data.empty())
            {
                m_cv.wait(lock, [&](){ return !m_data.empty(); }); // predicate an while loop - protection from spurious wakeups
            }
            while(!m_data.empty()) // consume all elements from queue
            {
                std::cout << "Consumer Thread, queue element: " << m_data.front() << " size: " << m_data.size() << std::endl;
                m_data.pop();
            }
        } while(!m_bFinished);
    }
};


int main()
{
    int QueueElements = 10;
    App app(QueueElements);
    std::thread consumer_thread(&App::Consumer, &app);
    std::thread producer_thread(&App::Producer, &app);

    producer_thread.join();
    consumer_thread.join();

    std::cout << "loop exited" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Also note, that it's better to use [atomic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) for end flag, when you have deal with concurrent threads, because theoretically value of the `m_bFinished` will be stored in the cache-line and if there is no cache invalidation in the producer thread, the changed value can be unseen from the consumer thread. Atomics have memory fences, that guarantees, that value will be updated for other threads.

Also you can take a look on [memory_order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the purpose of the sleep is purely to simulate different processing delays and will not be part of the final code.

Comment: You have duplicating logic. Either remove while loop around Conditional Variable, or remove predicate you pass to CV. They are doing same thing.